# Mouseover or div in the blocked elements in DHTMLX Scheduler in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using DHTMLX scheduler in my MVC application. I am blocking some times in the scheduler. While mouseovering or clicking the blocked elements i need to display a div or just a message is it possible to do ?

My controller code to display the blocked elements in the scheduler

```
public ContentResult Data(DateTime from, DateTime to)
        {
            var scheduler = new DHXScheduler(this);

            var user = (int)Session["UserID"];
            //var data = new SchedulerAjaxData(
            //     new SYTEntities().tblBusinessUserHolidays.Where(a => a.BusinessUserId == id && a.UserTypeId == 5).Select(e => new { id = e.Id, start_date = e.HolidayDate, text = e.HolidayDesc, end_date = "2015-07-08 10:30:00.000" })
            //    );
            var data = new SchedulerAjaxData(
                 new SYTEntities().tblApps.Where(a => a.UserId1 == user).Select(e => new { id = e.AppointmentID, start_date = e.StartDate, end_date = e.EndDate, text = e.Description, event_length = e.Event_length, event_pid = e.Event_pid, rec_type = e.rec_type })
                 );


            var blocked = new SYTEntities().tblApps
                          .Where(e => e.UserId1 != user && e.StartDate < to && e.EndDate >= from)
                          .Select(e => new { e.StartDate, e.EndDate }).ToList();

            // var res = new SchedulerAjaxData(data);`
           data.ServerList.Add("blocked_time", blocked);

            return Content(data);

        }
```

Script file is

```
[![window.schedulerClient = {
    init: function () {
        scheduler.serverList("blocked_time");//initialize server list before scheduler initialization

        scheduler.attachEvent("onXLS", function () {
            scheduler.config.readonly = true;
        });

        scheduler.attachEvent("onXLE", function () {
            var blocked = scheduler.serverList("blocked_time");
            schedulerClient.updateTimespans(blocked);
            blocked.splice(0, blocked.length);

            //make scheduler editable again and redraw it to display loaded timespans
            scheduler.config.readonly = false;
            scheduler.setCurrentView();
        });


    },

    updateTimespans: function (timespans) {
        // preprocess loaded timespans and add them to the scheduler
        for (var i = 0; i < timespans.length; i++) {
            var span = timespans\[i\];

            span.start_date = scheduler.templates.xml_date(span.StartDate);
            span.end_date = scheduler.templates.xml_date(span.EndDate);


            // add a label
            span.html = scheduler.templates.event_date(span.start_date) +
                " - " +
                scheduler.templates.event_date(span.end_date);


            //define timespan as 'blocked'
            span.type = "dhx_time_block";
            scheduler.deleteMarkedTimespan(span);// prevent overlapping

            scheduler.addMarkedTimespan(span);

            $(".dhx_scale_holder  ").mouseover(function () {

                alert("hi");

            })



        }
    }

};
```

[image: Message or div while hovering or clicking the blocked elements]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
       $(".dhx_cal_container").delegate(".dhx_time_block", "mouseover", function (event) {

             dhtmlx.message("Blocked ");

        });
</script>
```

I added the script code like this after that only it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use [onMouseMove](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_onmousemove_event.html) event from scheduler api, or you can catch event manually.
If you do the later - note that DOM elements of marked timespans are added and removed silently, i.e. it's better not to attach listeners directly to them but use event delegation instead:

```
// .dhx_cal_container - top node of dhtmlxScheduler
$(".dhx_cal_container").on("mouseover", ".dhx_time_block", function(event) {
    // do something
});
```

Here is a complete example:
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/snippet/263a0dfa

Comment: Hi, Thanks for ur reply. I have added this code in my application but there is no change while mouseover . Can u please help me?

Comment: In which place we need to specify that particular code which you mentioned above.